# Create rows for each minute in time ranges

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have such table in BigQuery:

| id | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 21:45:57 UTC | 2021-02-05 21:48:17 UTC |
| 2 | 2021-02-05 23:12:01 UTC | 2021-02-05 23:13:42 UTC |

I need to create rows for each minute incuded in time range between start_timestamp and end_timestamp.

expected result:

| id | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 21:45:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 21:46:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 21:46:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 21:47:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 21:47:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 21:48:00 UTC |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 21:48:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 21:49:00 UTC |
| 2 | 2021-02-05 23:12:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 23:13:00 UTC |
| 2 | 2021-02-05 23:13:00 UTC | 2021-02-05 23:14:00 UTC |

How can I do this with BigQuery?

example input data:

```
WITH
  example_table AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    TIMESTAMP('2021-02-05 21:45:57') AS start_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMP('2021-02-05 21:48:17') AS end_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 AS id,
    TIMESTAMP('2021-02-05 23:12:01') AS start_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMP('2021-02-05 23:13:42') AS end_timestamp)
SELECT * FROM example_table;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, 
  ts as start_timestamp, 
  ts + interval 1 minute as end_timestamp
from example_table,
unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
  timestamp_trunc(start_timestamp, minute), 
  timestamp_trunc(end_timestamp, minute), 
  interval 1 minute
) ) ts
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works as needed.